# How to stop Jest from scanning directories

Tags: jestjs

## Problem

My project directory has several large subdirectories with model data. Together, the model directories have over 1,500 subdirectories and 75,000 files.  I want to ignore them completely because they make the tests run extremely slowly; all the tests run and then I have to wait over a minute until the test shows as complete. I believe it is taking the time to scan the directories (evidence below).  I attempted to exclude them in various ways, most recently (the `mod92` are the big directories):

```js
    "testMatch": ["**/__tests__/*.js"],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/\\.git/", "/Mod92_.*/", "/mod92_.*/", "/\\.pytest_cache/", "/\\.vs*/", "/node_modules/", "/py_tests/", "/pyenv/"]
```

Neither that nor my previous attempts worked.  But if I move the `mod92*` directories out of the project, the tests run instantly.  So it seems the directories are being scanned despite the ignore patterns.

Is there a way to skip the directories?

Here's the directory structure of the project, before I moved the problem directories:

```
__tests__
bin
   js
   python
data
master
.git
.vscode
# many other dot directories
mod92_abc
Mod92_def
mod92_xyz
# and many more
```

The tests are in `__tests__`, but might in the future be under `bin/js/__tests__` as well.  The code being tested is in `bin/js`.

## `roots`: A False Solution?

`root` or `roots` appear to limit the search for tests, but it sounds as if they limit the search for code as well.  If I set the root to `__tests__` this will exclude the code I'm testing, under `bin/js`.  I'm not entirely sure why `Jest` is looking for general code at all, since all my references to it use explicit, relative paths.

Setting the root to `__tests__` would also prevent finding tests under `bin/js/__tests__`, which doesn't exist now but might in the future.

By the way, one of the reasons I am using a top-level `__tests__` is that the tests refer to other top-level directories like `data`, and it seemed easier to do so from the top.

## Pattern Problems?

Or maybe something is wrong with the patterns:

1. I should use relative paths like `\\./mod92.*/` instead of absolute ones.  But that's not what the documentation shows, and I tried it and it didn't work.
2. Since I'm on MS-Windows I should `\` as the path separator, not `/`.  I believe the necessary javascript would need to use quadruple `\` to end up with a regex that had one.
3. The `/` in the examples is actually for a JavaScript regex literal, `/pattern/`, read from a string.  But the examples include strings that are not surrounded by `/`, and it would be weird if they were used that way since creating a regex from a string does not require such quoting.

Some discussion (mostly of older versions of `Jest`) shows counts of the number of matches to the ignore patterns.  This suggests that the "excluded" directories are actually still traversed.  If that's the case, I need some other way to stop the traversal.

## Environment

- Jest 29.7
- Node.js 20.9.0
- VSCode 1.86.0 with [vscode-jest](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest) 5.2.3 as extension for testing
- MS Windows Server 2019 Standard, v1809.

Comment: What is your project structure like, specifically the relationship between `__tests__` and the `mod92` dirs? Should be able to use the `roots` in combination with the `<rootDir>` token and negated globs.

Comment: @morganney I added a directory tree to the bottom of the problem section, and reworked the discussion of roots in the next section.  In short, `__tests__` and `mod92*` are at the same directory level, and an apparent obstacle to using `roots` is that the code is under a different top level directory, `bin`.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `roots` and explicitly list all the directories you want jest to scan? Have you tried that yet?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong in my experience:

> Setting the root to _*tests*_ would also prevent finding tests under bin/js/_*tests*_, which doesn't exist now but might in the future.

You should be able to configure multiple directories for your test files, so I would try explicitly listing all the directories you want Jest to scan using `roots`:

> A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in.

Here is an example of what I am thinking, including multiple `__tests__` directories. This assumes your tests don't depend on the files being excluded (since you said tests pass when you remove them), and you only want to test source files under `master` and `data` as an example (since you never indicated where your source files under test actually live).

```js
roots: [
  '<rootDir>/__tests__/',
  '<rootDir>/bin/js/__tests__/',
  '<rootDir>/data/',
  '<rootDir>/master/'
],
testMatch: [
  '<rootDir>/__tests__/**/*.js',
  '<rootDir>/bin/js/__tests__/**/*.js'
]
```

You need to also list each directory containing tests under `testMatch`.